# How to fix "This plugin hasn’t been tested with the latest 3 major releases of WordPress. It..." on my own plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, readme

Saw this message at the top of my plugin today and decided I should fix that.

I updated my readme.txt file to say:

```
Requires at least: 5.0

Tested up to: 5.4.1

Requires PHP: 5.6

Stable tag: 1.1.8

License: GPLv2 or later
```

I committed changes almost 6 hours ago and it still says this message at the top. Did I miss somewhere else that I'm supposed to update to get this message to go away? I can barely find any information on how to deal with this kind of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the same issue, I know it's late, but hopefully can further help any other who doesn't know.

Please see the [description](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-developer-faq/#why-does-my-plugin-say-its-not-been-tested-with-the-most-recent-wordpress-versions) of this issue from wordpress.org.

- Just simply change the `Tested up to` from `5.4.1` to the latest version like `5.8`.

And be sure to update your remote SVN by following:

- `checkout` your remote svn, then edit your file, then `commit` your change.

This will figure the trick.

Here is user [guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-to-use-subversion/) of SVN from wordpress.